# CakePHP permissions management plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, user-interface, cakephp-1.3

I'm specially looking for a good UI to manage permissions of users/groups based on CakePHP's auth and acl components.

is anyone knows a good plugin (or good working code) to manage users and their permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you what I am using in the moment: [Authake](http://github.com/nchankov/authake). It's not using the Cake's native Auth classes and tables, but for me it's enough to manage the Authorization and Authentication in my projects